# Spring Test @SqlGroup with @PostConstruct on bean

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm trying to execute some SQL statements with @SqlGroup before running some integration tests using *Spring 5, Junit4.11 and JDK8.*

Everything was working flawless until today, when I added some initial configuration on my "ConfigurationComponent" bean, with the annotation @PostConstruct.

As @PostConstruct method calls a database-dependent bean, the test fails, because hiberante (thus the database) can't find the preloaded schema.

As I investigated, I found that statements put in @SqlGroup will execute after ApplicationContext initialization, so the @PostConstruct is executed before the schema is loaded.

**Here is my integration test abstract class.**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-context-test.xml" })
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = {
                "classpath:db_config.sql",
                "classpath:consultas/setup_esquema_0.1.sql",
                "classpath:db_datos_iniciales.sql"}),
        @Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:db_teardown.sql") })
public abstract class AbstractServiceTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public abstract void setUp() throws Exception;

    @After
    public abstract void tearDown() throws Exception;

    public static Long randomId() {
        return new Long(Math.round(Math.random() * 1000));
    }

}
```

**The offending bean**

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationComponent {

    @Autowired
    Resources resources; // resources are retrieved from database.

    @PostConstruct
    public void startUp() throws VariableGlobalInexistenteException {
        Config.environment = resources
                .getWsaaEnv();
        Config.validation = resources
                .getWsaaEnvValidation();
    }

}
```

I can't find a way to overcome this issue using @SqlGroup. Is there any solution, a way to alter the lifecycle and execute the sql statements first?.
As you can see, I'm using `ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD`, there is no
explicit configuration for this case, like "ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_SETUP".

---

*Update 09-07-2018 - Looks like there is no way of achieving this using @Sql:*

> Both @Sql and the calling of @PostConstruct are handled by Spring
>   Framework rather than Spring Boot. Also, I believe this is working as
>   designed. The default execution phase for @Sql is BEFORE_TEST_METHOD
>   (the other option is AFTER_TEST_METHOD). The application context is
>   refreshed, and therefore @PostConstruct is called, once for the whole
>   test class (in fact it could be once for multiple test classes if they
>   share the same configuration) which happens before individual test
>   methods are called. In other words, you cannot use @Sql as a means of
>   preparing the database for calls that are made in @PostConstruct.

[Github @PostConstruct executed before @Sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13761)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find a workaround. As the latest update stated, there is no way of achieving the desired behavior using @SqlGroup. I've had to use the following approach, using @BeforeClass and @AfterClass:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(conn, new ClassPathResource("db_config.sql"));
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(conn, new ClassPathResource("consultas/setup_schema"));
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(conn, new ClassPathResource("db_init.sql"));
    JdbcUtils.closeConnection(conn);

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = getDataSource().getConnection();
    ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(conn, new ClassPathResource(
            "db_teardown.sql"));
    JdbcUtils.closeConnection(conn);
}

private static DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    return dataSource;
}
```

All @SqlGroup annotations were removed. This methodology is quite clean, as ScriptUtils doesn't need much dependencies to run.

Comment: This comes close to a solution, but what about having multiple tests in that class and each of them require a clean DB state? E.g. test 1 is doing some write or delete operations, then test 2 cannot rely on the (now modified) data. BeforeClass and AfterClass do not fulfill that requirement.

Comment: @J.Doe hey. I don't have that issue because I use Transactional on my tests. This prompts a rollback after each test case is completed, thus leaving the database as-is on the first init. You can also play around with the Before and After annotation to cleanup the DB state.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, even after 4 years :D! That's indeed a good solution then, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround would be implementing CommandLineRunner.

```
@Component
public class ConfigurationInitRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    Resources resources; // resources are retrieved from database.

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        Config.environment = resources.getWsaaEnv();
        Config.validation = resources.getWsaaEnvValidation();
    }
}
```